# Trouble with using gorilla/mux package in mac

Tags: go, mux, gopath, go-packages

I am trying to learn how to build a webserver using go and mux. I am importing mux to the main.go file as `import github.com/gorilla/mux`. However, when I am trying to run the code. I get the following error

```
no required module provides package github.com/gorilla/mux: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
```

My GOPATH is `/Users/michiokaku/Study/go`

The overall structure of my directories is

```
go___
     pkg
     bin
     my_codes___
                main.go
```

Inside pkg, I found a directory named mux@v1.8.0 in the path `pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla`. I think this is what I downloaded using `go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux`. But when the code is running, I am getting errors.

What is the issue here? How do I solve this?

PS: I am using mac.

Comment: run `go mod init` in your project directory

Comment: Tried that. It gave an error saying 'can not determine the module path for source directory /Users/michiokaku/Study/go_my_codes (outside GOPATH, module path must be specified)

Comment: What do they mean by this?

Comment: No, modules can be outside of the gopath. What did you run ? It should be `go mod init <module_name>`

Comment: Oh, okay. I just run go mode init. I should be running go mod init github.com/gorilla/mux right?

Comment: I did that. Now it says, import cycle not allowed

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://golang.org/doc/code. The tutorial should answer your question.

Comment: Even this is giving me an import cycle not allowed error

Comment: Delete go.mod to get back to square one. Run go mod init example.com/user/hello as shown in the tutorial.  Follow steps in section on importing a remote package.

Answer (score 2):

Read through [Tutorial: Getting Started with Go](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started), if you haven't seen it already. It matches your situation pretty closely.

In short:

- Run `go mod init example.com/projectname`, replacing the last argument with the name for your module. This will create a `go.mod` file in the current directory that will track your dependencies. Your module's name will be a prefix for all packages within your module.
- Run `go mod tidy` or `go get github.com/gorilla/mux` to add `github.com/gorilla/mux` as a dependency.

You mentioned you saw a directory `pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla` earlier. This is part of Go's [module cache](https://golang.org/ref/mod#module-cache), shared by all projects.

Comment: I followed this. and I am getting an error saying, import cycle not allowed

Comment: @MichioKaku That error happens if a package imports itself directly or indirectly. In the `go mod init` command, did you name your project `github.com/gorilla/mux`? If so, change the name to something else by editing the module line in go.mod or by running `go mod edit -module=example.com/somethingelse`. If not, please add more info.

Comment: What should I write as something else here? I didn’t really understand your suggestion. Can you elaborate? Can I simply replace github.com/mypackage or something like that? And Use the same name to import it into my go code?

Comment: @MichioKaku update your question by adding the contents of the `go.mod` file, and also add the whole import-cycle error message, it usually lists the packages in the cycle making it quite clear where the problem is.

Comment: @MichioKaku If you're uploading your project anywhere that others might import it, use a name that matches the repository location. For GitHub, that's something like github.com/yourid/yourrepo. If no one will import packages in your project, you can use any valid name like "example" or "local" or "test".